# Indexing duplicates in a matrix: Matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing

Consider a matrix

```
 X = [ 1 2 0 1; 
       1 0 1 2;                                          
       1 2 3 4;                                     
       2 4 6 8;
          .           
          .                          
       1 2 0 1                  
          .                 
          .    ]
```

I want to create a new column such that I can number `ith` occurence of every row.

Ans:

```
   X = [ 1 2 0 1;   y =  [1
         1 0 1 2;         1                                 
         1 2 3 4;         1                            
         2 4 6 8;         1
           .             .
           .             .             
         1 2 0 1          2        
           .             .    
           .    ]        .]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
y = sum(triu(squareform(pdist(X))==0)).';
```

This works by counting how many previous rows are equal to each row. Two rows are equal if their distance (computed with [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/squareform.html) and [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/pdist.html)) is 0. [`triu`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) makes sure only previous rows are taken into account.

To reduce computation time and avoid depending on the Statistics Toolbox, you can use @user1735003's suggestion:

```
y = sum(triu((bsxfun(@plus, sum(X.^2,2), sum(X.^2,2)') - 2*X*X.')==0));
```

Comment: May I suggest `sum(triu((bsxfun(@plus, sum(X.^2,2), sum(X.^2,2)') - 2*X*X')==0))` that doesn't require the statistical toolbox's `pdist`.

Comment: @user1735003 Think it's alternative would be - `sum(triu(squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,X,permute(X,[3 2 1])).^2,2)))==0))` to reduce one `sum`.

Comment: ... or, perhaps faster: `sum(triu(squeeze(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@ne,X,permute(X,[3 2 1])),2)))==0))` @Divakar

Comment: @LuisMendo Smart move! Yeah that should work too for this special case. Think you should add that? +1

Comment: @Divar user1735003's approach seems to be faster. I wonder if the distance computation can be improved over that

Comment: @LuisMendo Did you try your `@ne` approach without that `sqrt`? I still can't believe that `extra-sum` approach beating `@ne` approach.

Comment: @Divakar Well spotted, that saves time. But it's still slower (on my computer, with the `X` of your answer)

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

```
%// unique rows
unqrows = unique(X,'rows'); 

%// matches for each row against the unique rows and their cumsum values
matches_perunqrow = squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,X,permute(unqrows,[3 2 1])),2));
cumsum_unqrows = cumsum(matches_perunqrow,1);

%// Go through a row-order and get the cumsum values for the final output
[row,col] = find(matches_perunqrow);
[sorted_row,ind] = sort(row);
y=cumsum_unqrows(sub2ind(size(cumsum_unqrows),[1:size(cumsum_unqrows,1)]',col(ind)));
```

Sample run -

```
X =
     1     2     0     1
     1     0     1     2
     1     2     3     4
     2     4     6     8
     1     2     0     1
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     0     1
out =
     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
     4
     5
     3
```

---

**Approach #2**

```
%// unique rows
unqrows = unique(X,'rows');

%// matches for each row against the unique rows
matches_perunqrow = all(bsxfun(@eq,X,permute(unqrows,[3 2 1])),2)

%// Get the cumsum of matches and select only the matches for each row.
%// Since we need to go through a row-order, transpose the result
cumsum_perrow = squeeze(cumsum(matches_perunqrow,1).*matches_perunqrow)' %//'

%// Select the non zero values for the final output
y = cumsum_perrow(cumsum_perrow~=0)
```

---

**Approach #3**

```
%// label each row based on their uniqueness
[~,~,v3] = unique(X,'rows')
matches_perunqrow = bsxfun(@eq,v3,1:size(X,1))

cumsum_unqrows = cumsum(matches_perunqrow,1);

%// Go through a row-order and get the cumsum values for the final output
[row,col] = find(matches_perunqrow);
[sorted_row,ind] = sort(row);
y=cumsum_unqrows(sub2ind(size(cumsum_unqrows),[1:size(cumsum_unqrows,1)]',col(ind)));
```

---

**Approach #4**

```
%// label each row based on their uniqueness
[~,~,match_row_id] = unique(X,'rows');

%// matches for each row against the unique rows and their cumsum values
matches_perunqrow = bsxfun(@eq,match_row_id',[1:size(X,1)]');
cumsum_unqrows = cumsum(matches_perunqrow,2);

%// Select the cumsum values for the ouput based on the unique matches for each row
y = cumsum_unqrows(matches_perunqrow);
```

Comment: Mind adding some explanations? It is not quite easily readable. Also some quick tests with your sample run didn't show a speed increase compared to my loop version. 20000 repititions took 3.3s for my version and 4.7s and 3.6s for your two versions. Maybe it does for other sample runs. I generally like your solutions, but this time I neither see an increase in readability, nor in speed... yet.

Comment: @Nras I am adding comments as we speak actually! :)

Comment: @Nras Edited with comments. There might be optimizations possible though to remove `squeeze` and `transposing`. I will check for speed at my end too.

Comment: alright, I am pretty sure that ``squeeze()`` can always be replaced by calling ``reshape()`` directly, if one is not too lazy to figure out the dimensions. If you're doing the speed tests, I am very happy with that and leave it for you. You did an awesome job with that the other day on one of my answers :-).

Comment: Very thorough! Thanks.

Comment: @Nras That turned out to be nice answer in the end ;) Some good experiments were run for that answer, good memories!

Answer (score 1):

A solution including a for loop can be done quite easily, maybe it is fast enough already. I am confident that there is a faster solution, which might makes use of `cumsum`, but maybe you do not even need it. The basic idea: find the indices of unique rows first, in order to be able to deal with scalar indices instead of full rows (vectors).
Then loop over the indices and find number of previous occurences:

```
X = [ 1 2 0 1; 
   1 0 1 2;                                          
   1 2 3 4;                                     
   2 4 6 8;                        
   1 2 0 1;                 
   1 3 3 7;                 
   1 2 0 1];

[~,~,idx] = unique(X, 'rows'); %// find unique rows

%// loop over indices and accumulate number of previous occurences
y = zeros(size(idx));
for i = 1:length(idx)
   y(i) = sum(idx(1:i) == idx(i)); %// this line probably scales horrible with length of idx.
end
```

The result for the example is:

```
y =

 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 1
 3
```

Comment: This seems to be fast indeed for most cases. I just believe more in vectorization, personal choice I guess, as also because I think GPUs stand a good chance with vectorized codes.  So, as a special case when I used `X = randi(10,4000,2000);` and gpuArray for `match_row_id` in my solution, the runtimes actually become comparable with the loopy code and I have a decent GPU for testing. +1

Comment: @Divakar I also like the challenge of vectorizing code. Did you try to rewrite your ``bsxfun`` part with a explicit for-loop and then apply the rest of your your approaches? Though ``bsxfun`` offering usage of nice and short code, it may be slower than looped-versions. In terms of optimizing for speed, this might very well be an issue.

Comment: Writing a for-loop to replace just the `bsxfun` part won't yield any improvement. I think as a loopy code, yours is perfect.